# Proof by contradiction$\,-\,$functional equation

Tags: proof-verification, functional-equations

Show that there does not exist a strictly increasing function $f : N → N $ satisfying $f (2) = 3$ and $f (mn) = f (m)f (n)$ for all $m, n ∈ N$.

**My Attempt**

It can be found that $f(2^x)=3^x$ from which we can conclude that $f(x)=3^{\log_2 x}$ and by which we can argue that for all natural $x$, $f(x)$ is not always natural, so contradiction hence such a function doesn't exist.
Is this proof correct? If not what should be changed?

Comment: No, it's not correct. Your claim that $f(2^x) = 3^x$ implies $f(x)=3^{\log_2 x}$ is not a valid claim. All you know is It holds if $x$ is a positive integer power of $2$ (but then there's no contradiction).

Comment: Why is that? Can you please explain?

Comment: @quasi Then how'd you suggest that I solve it?

Comment: Start by bounding $f(3)$.

Comment: $9=f(4)>f(3)>f(2)=3$

Comment: Suppose $f(3) = 4$. Can you find an easy contradiction based on relatively small inputs (less than $20$) to $f$?

Comment: Fool with the assumption $f(3) = 4$, just to explore. The assumption $f(3)=4$ tells you very little about values of $f$ such as $f(5)$. So forget those kinds of inputs. Focus on the ones that are fully determined by the assumption $f(3)=4$.

Comment: Then $f(9) = f(3)\cdot f(3) = 16$, but $f(8) = 27$. Contradiction.

Comment: Fun problem.  I've narrowed $f(3)$ down to $f(3) \in \{6, 7, 8\}$.

Comment: @quasi I figured out the contradiction. So is this it? I mean we assume so I think there should be more. Right?

Comment: If all you proved is $f(3) \ne 4$, then you're definitely not done. But can you show $f(3) > 5$?

Comment: Yes, we have that.

Comment: You might need to bring more primes into play (e.g., $f(5)$).

Comment: Yes I can show that $f(9)>27 \implies f(3)>5$

Comment: I haven't solved the problem -- just fooled with it a little. But at least I gave you some insights as to how you might proceed.

Comment: But I think this is not the way to go. There must be something smart.

Comment: Have at it -- I don't have time to play.

Comment: If $f(3) = 6$, then $f(5) = 13$.

Comment: Take some higher powers, for example $3^5 = 243 < 256 = 2^8$, so we must have $f(3)^5 < f(2)^8 = 3^8 = 6561$.

Comment: Proof: First of all $9 < f(5) < 18$. Now, $f(9) = 36$ and $f(10) = 3f(5)$. Hence, $13\le f(5) < 18$. Also, $f(15) = 6f(5)$ and $f(16) = 3^4 = 81$. this shows $f(5)\le 13$.

Comment: $f(3)$ must be $6$ (since $f(3)^3 < f(32) = 243$).

Comment: @quasi If you got that, then by Daniel Fischer's comment, we are done.

Comment: So perhaps my suggestions were not so _dumb_ after all?

Comment: @quasi ;o) I did not say _dumb_.

Comment: @quasi Do you want to write the answer?

Comment: No, it's ok -- no time. Someone else can do it.

Comment: Ok, I will do it.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(3) < 6$, then $27 = f(8) < f(9)\le 25$, a contradiction. Now, assume that $f(3) > 6$. Then $343 = 7^3 \le f(3)^3 = f(27) < f(32) = 3^5 = 243$. Again a contradiction. Thus, $f(3) = 6$. But then $7776 = 6^5 = f(3)^5 = f(243) < f(256) = f(2^8) = 3^8 = 6561$. Done.

Most of the work was done by quasi and Daniel Fischer (see the comments).

Comment: Argh, I was so close!

Comment: OK, one last fix:  shouldn't it be $7776 = 6^5 = f(3)^5$.....

Comment: Yes, fixed it....

Comment: OK, now I can sleep.